# Probably an easy question: $e^{2\ln(3)}$ without a calculator

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to evaluate $e^{2\ln(3)}$ without using a calculator? I've tried playing with $\ln$ but couldn't figure out

Comment: $a\ln(b)=\ln(b^a)$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint

\begin{align}
e^{2 \ln 3} &= e^{\ln (3^{2})} \\
&= \ldots
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$$e^{2 \ln 3} = (e^{\ln 3})^2 = 3^2 = 9 $$